# your connection is not private error in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I have created Node js server. My ubuntu system running with two servers apache in port 443 and node js server running in port 442. Apache server running fine with SSL Certificate and but Node js is showing SSL error.
[image]
**Your Connection is not private** 
**server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var inbox=require('./functions.js');
var app = express();

// This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
var options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/biz.key'),
 cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/biz.crt')
};

 // Create a service (the app object is just a callback).

 app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
 next();
});


 // Create an HTTP service.
 http.createServer(app).listen(81);
 // Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
 https.createServer(options, app).listen(442,function () {
   console.log('Server Time'+new Date().Now());
 });
```

**Edit:**
Once I click advanced and proceed to insecure server. Then it's working green padding showing in browser.

Comment: It complaints about the authority. Shall we assume it isn't a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Where did you get your `biz.key` and `/etc/ssl/biz.crt` .. Are they self signed ?

Comment: you should link key and cert in options to the same resource as apache is using

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález No they are original. Not self assinged bought from GoDaddy. It's working fine with apache.

Comment: @Pogrindis no they are not self assigned.

Comment: Why people giving down votes. Is this question in appropriate? or poorly framed? It's not even a common problem.

Comment: Apache having a license doesn't help you if you aren't using apache.

Comment: Can you troubleshoot with a regular desktop browser, so you can inspect the certificate served?

Comment: You don't need your https handler at all, just proxy your requests through apache.

Comment: I already tried apache proxy it's failed. the same path is given in apache also.

Answer (score 3):

Your node https config isn't sending intermediate certificates. Use the `ca` option to send these for the client to be able to form a complete chain.

```
var options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/biz.key'),
 cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/biz.crt'),
 ca: <insert your ca bundle here>
};
```

If your site served from Apache (over port 443) also shows up with this warning in your mobile browser, you'll have to do something something similar in Apache. You can use [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to test your site's certificates and other TLS settings.